# In SPSS modeler (17/18), what is criteria for evaluating ties encountered while sorting particular column using sorting nugget?

Tags: sorting, spss, spss-modeler

Am sorting by particular column using sorting nugget in SPSS modeler 17/18. However, do not understand how ties are evaluated when values are repeated in sorting column. None of the other columns have any sequence associated with it? Can someone throw some light on this.

Have attached illustration here where am sorting on col3 (excel file is original data). However, after sorting, no other cols (Key) seem to follow any sequence/order. How was final data arrived at then? [image]

Comment: Per the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_18.0.0/modeler_mainhelp_client_ddita/clementine/performance_nodes_process.html), it seems like it's using hybrid quick sort / merge sort.. For a small amount of data like this, probably a quick sort.  Depending on how they choose their pivot point, ties could show up in a different order than originally

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find any documentation to answer this question, but I believe that the order of ties after the sort is essentially *random* or at least determined by a number of factors that are outside of the user's control. Generally, I think it is determined by the order of the records in the source, but if you are querying a database or similar without specifying a sort order, you may see that the data will be sorted differently depending on the source system and it may even differ between each execution.

If your processing depends on the sort order of the data (including the order of the ties), the best approach will be to specify the sort order in such a detail that ties will not happen.